Getting 'token' undefined in api.js when registering a user through the front end
Undefined token, or token is null at api.js, none of the console.logs are triggered. so unsure how to troubleshoot at this point. chatGPT no help.
api.js
import { fetchBaseQuery, createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    // baseUrl: "https://capstonebackend-0wah.onrender.com/",
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
    tagTypes: ["User"],

    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = getState().register.token || getState().login.token;
      const sessionToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem("Token", token);
      if (token || sessionToken) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token || sessionToken}`);
      }
    },
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});

registerSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { api } from "../../app/api";

const registerApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    register: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: "/register",
        method: "POST",
        body: credentials,
        responseHandler: (response) => response.text(),
      }),
      invalidateTags: ["User"],
    }),
  }),
});

const registerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "register",
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    token: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      console.log("Setting user in login:", action.payload);
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      registerApi.endpoints.register.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        console.log(payload);
        const temp = JSON.parse(payload);
        console.log(temp);
        state.token = temp.token;
        // state.user = temp;
        // state.id = temp.id;
        // window.sessionStorage.setItem("Token", temp.token);
        // window.sessionStorage.setItem("User", temp.id);
      }
    );
  },
});

export default registerSlice.reducer;

export const { useRegisterMutation } = registerApi;

export const {  setUser } = registerSlice.actions;



Whenever I submit a registerUser request through the frontend it is getting token undefined. I put breakpoints in and found it is undefined in the api.js. It doesn't seem like it is even triggering the registerSlice. Tested the backend in Postman and it can register a user and get a token just fine. How can I fix this to get the token to be passed correctly?

Are you getting back the token when you send a register request to the server? You should inspect your network tab to see if the server is returning the token at all.

Why are you storing the token in potentially two places in the store? Are the state paths correct? Do you get the expected token value back from the endpoints that provide it?

There is no POST request being triggered in the network tab. I am not getting anything back in the frontend at this point, I am only getting a token value in the backend when I register through Postman

If i remove the "prepare headers" code, it works and returns a token. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Barring any issue with the state or sessionStorage access the only issue I see in the prepareHeaders callback is that it doesn't return the headers for the request to be made.
Update to return the headers object you'd like to be used for the requests.
prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
  const { login, register } = getState();

  const token = register.token || login.token;
  const sessionToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem("Token", token);
  const authToken = token || sessionToken;

  if (authToken) {
    headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${authToken}`);
  }

  return headers; // <-- return the headers to be used for each request
},

